# iOS 10 Preferences crashes when trying to add my custom keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, xcode8, ios10, ios-keyboard-extension

I am trying to develop  my custom keyboard extension. 
When i am trying to actually enable my keyboard from the settings it crashes. I go settings->general->keyboard->keyboards -> settings app crashes here. 
My device log look like this:

```
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x183774108 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
    3   Foundation                      0x18415f45c -[NSCountedSet addObject:] + 92
    4   KeyboardSettings                0x1984a8058 +[TIKeyboardListController keyboardDisplayNameForIdentifier:] + 476
    5   KeyboardSettings                0x1984a41a8 -[TIInputModeTableCell title] + 168
.....
```

So seems like this is somehow related to my extension display name. It is "SebastianCatKeyboard". I've tried to change it several times but crash is still there.

When i remove my container app with extension settings are not crashing. So this is definitely related to my keyboard.

I would really appreciate any help.

Many thanks.